# Блоку «похожие вопросы» на странице задания вопроса не хватает отступов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

На странице https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask к жёлтому блоку «похожие вопросы» (справа) нужно добавить какой-нибудь padding:

> [image]

Comment: Похожий вопрос на Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313020/alignment-issue-in-the-similar-questions-side-bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исправлено в последней сборке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]